# python ctypes precision

Tags: python, c++, double, precision, ctypes

I am using `ctypes` to create a wrapper over a C++ library (.so). I ran into some trouble with the precision of an argument. When I pass `math.pi` as a `double`, I am only getting six decimal places of precision, i.e. 3.141593000. This is introducing a small but significant error when I calculate sines and cosines.

As I understand, `double` should have 15 decimal places of precision and `math.pi` indeed gives 15 decimal places in python. What could be the problem in this situation? Has anybody else ran into this issue? How did you solve it?

Comment: Some clarification as to what steps you took would be helpful, since `ctypes` doesn't directly contain a `double` type. It contains `c_double` and `c_longdouble`, which represent the C types `double` and `long double` respectively.

Comment: Yes, I should've made it clear. I am using ```c_double``` to pass the argument, and when I read it in, I use a ```double```.

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please show your code. Based on the comments, I see the possibility that the way you are currently handling things might be completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, passing `math.pi` into `ctypes.c_double` should return `c_double(3.141592653589793)`. Here's an example in Python 3.11.1:

```py
>>> import math
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.c_double(math.pi)
c_double(3.141592653589793)
```

My only guess is that you're not using `ctypes.c_double`, but perhaps some other double type that has less precision. Check out the [`ctypes` type conversion table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) to see all the ctypes conversions.

Comment: You are right, ```c_double``` should do the job. 
I found the issue. The ```double``` was being stored as a string somewhere in the middle of the process using ```'%e'``` to parse it and then it was being parsed back to a double. This was reducing the precision significantly. Thanks for the help!